# Whenever I open my home (~) folder with nautilus, there is an endless loading

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, filesystem

Ubuntu 14.04. Kernel 3.13.1-031301-generic.

If I change to another folder the endless loading (*) from hard drive stops.

I don't have much in that folder.

Any idea what might cause that, or how I can investigate the cause?

Thanks!

- P.S. I don't see in the bottom right corner the "loading...", but there is an endless access to the hard drive.

Comment: @JacobVlijm About 100 files.

Comment: That can't be it...

Comment: Any messages in `dmesg` or `/var/log/syslog`? reading problems?

Comment: @Xen2050 Nothing new is written to /var/log/syslog when I open this folder.

Answer (score 0):

In this case in the logs, no news is good news. If there were errors that could mean the disk or filesystem was going bad.

I saw a bug report about a "cleaner" program that would write thousands of files, that caused Nautilus to never "load" the folder either, but if there's not many files (looking in terminal) that's not it...

Maybe a weird corrupted file in the folder, Nautilus keeps trying to read to get a thumbnail or something? Try moving some files to another directory, check if Nautilus works in both, move some more... find the bad one? Or see if the folder works with no files in it?

Comment: Yes I was thinking about that. There are many hidden directories there so I was wondering if moving them temporarily to other location would lock the system. Is there anything in Ubuntu that must be in the `~` folder for the OS core not to break down other then certain applications that might not function?

Comment: Mainly config files, but `.config` (& probably `.gnome` or similar, each DE can be different) has lots of the desktop settings, like panel bars, desktop image, colors & fonts. Nothing that can't be set again. Try searching for your particular desktop (unity?) to know for sure, but just for testing should be ok, and move back when done should be good as before